# How to Test mapped Objects in golang

Tags: go, testing, mocking

I try to implement some unit testing in my go code and find the topic of mocking method quite difficult.
I have the following example where I hope you can help me :)

On the first layer I have the following code:

```
package api

import (
    "fmt"
    "core"
)

type createUserDTO struct {
    Id string
}

func ApiMethod() {
    fmt.Println("some incoming api call wit user")
    incomingUserData := &createUserDTO{Id: "testId"}
    mapedUser := incomingUserData.mapUser()
    mapedUser.Create()
}

func (createUserDTO *createUserDTO) mapUser() core.User {
    return &core.UserCore{Id: createUserDTO.Id}
}
```

The second layer has the following code:

```
package core

import (
    "fmt"
)

type CoreUser struct{ Id string }

type User interface {
    Create()
}

func (user CoreUser) Create() {
    fmt.Println("Do Stuff")
}
```

My question now is, how do I test every public method in the api package without testing the core package. Especially the method Create().

Comment: This is very difficult to answer; as written your code does nothing except produce side-effects, which is very difficult to test for (and arguably something you shouldn't even be _trying_ to test for).  Even harder in this case because the side effects are entirely internal to the funcs, providing no external surface that can be tested.  I suspect you have attempted to simplify your use case for the purposes of asking the question, but you have perhaps gone too far?

Comment: yes this is a highly simplified representation. The goal was to separate the architecture layers as much as possible. Therefore each level has its own user object. Like UserDTO, UserCore, UserDB. I may have to think differently about the architecture with go. If that is the case, could you give me an example how to write this use case of creating a User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, I put together a trivial GitHub repository to show how I usually deal with structuring projects in Go. The repository doesn't take into consideration the test part for now but it should be pretty easy to insert them with this project structure.
Let's start with the general folders' layout:

- `controllers`
- `services`
- `db`
- `dto`
- `models`

Now, let's see the relevant files.

###### `models/user.go`

```golang
package models

import "gorm.io/gorm"

type User struct {
    *gorm.Model
    Id string `gorm:"primaryKey"`
}

func NewUser(id string) *User {
    return &User{Id: id}
}
```

Simple struct definition here.

###### `dto/user.go`

```golang
package dto

import "time"

type UserDTO struct {
    Id      string    `json:"id"`
    AddedOn time.Time `json:"added_on"`
}

func NewUserDTO(id string) *UserDTO {
    return &UserDTO{Id: id}
}
```

We enrich the model struct with a dummy `AddedOn` field which needs only for the sake of the demo.

###### `db/user.go`

```golang
package db

import (
    "gorm.io/gorm"

    "userapp/models"
)

type UserDb struct {
    Conn *gorm.DB
}

type UserDbInterface interface {
    SaveUser(user *models.User) error
}

func (u *UserDb) SaveUser(user *models.User) error {
    if dbTrn := u.Conn.Create(user); dbTrn.Error != nil {
        return dbTrn.Error
    }
    return nil
}
```

Here, we define an interface for using the `User` repository. In our tests, we can provide a mock instead of an instance of the `UserDb` struct.

###### `services/user.go`

```golang
package services

import (
    "time"

    "userapp/db"
    "userapp/dto"
    "userapp/models"
)

type UserService struct {
    DB db.UserDbInterface
}

type UserServiceInterface interface {
    AddUser(inputReq *dto.UserDTO) (*dto.UserDTO, error)
}

func NewUserService(db db.UserDbInterface) *UserService {
    return &UserService{
        DB: db,
    }
}

func (u *UserService) AddUser(inputReq *dto.UserDTO) (*dto.UserDTO, error) {
    // here you can write complex logic
    user := models.NewUser(inputReq.Id)

    // invoke db repo
    if err := u.DB.SaveUser(user); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    inputReq.AddedOn = time.Now()

    return inputReq, nil
}
```

This is the layer that bridges connections between the presentation layer and the underlying repositories.

###### `controllers/user.go`

```golang
package controllers

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io"
    "net/http"

    "userapp/dto"
    "userapp/services"
)

type UserController struct {
    US services.UserServiceInterface
}

func NewUserController(userService services.UserServiceInterface) *UserController {
    return &UserController{
        US: userService,
    }
}

func (u *UserController) Save(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    reqBody, err := io.ReadAll(r.Body)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    r.Body.Close()

    var userReq dto.UserDTO

    json.Unmarshal(reqBody, &userReq)

    userRes, err := u.US.AddUser(&userReq)
    if err != nil {
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(err)
        return
    }

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(userRes)
}
```

Here, we defined the controller that (through Dependency Injection) uses the `UserService` struct.

You can find everything in my repository on [GitHub](https://github.com/ivan-pesenti/userapp)
Let me know if it clarifies a little bit.

Comment: wow thanks for the effort you put into this. As far as I understand, the trick here is not to subordinate the models to the layer but to leave them separately. This also avoids circular dependencies. What bothers me is that the service layer has to know the structure of the DTO's. So I would have to adjust the service layer if I just wanted to display the user differently for other use cases.

Comment: you're welcome! In the service layer, I usually do the logic, such as contacting third-party systems, mapping stuff, and so on. Every method defined here will act on its own DTO which can be very different even if they're "based" on the same model. The GetUserReq can have different fields from PostUserReq, and so on. Here you can achieve the segregation you're concerned at. Moreover, you can restrict access to some data to the end user.

Comment: @TheBohne if this solves your issue, can you mark it as the accepted answer? Otherwise, if you need to clarify something else let me know! thanks

Comment: Currently the best answer to answer the question. I'm not 100% convinced yet due to the not quite separated layers. But it fits :) thanks.

Comment: I think that at a certain point one of your layers should be aware of DTOs. This layer usually is the Service layer. It's pretty common to have a mapping layer that maps "DTO" instances to "model" ones. This layer is injected into the service layer. In this way, you can decouple your entities from DTOs which only need to carry data from one layer to another. As an example, you can see this article which explains the role of DTO in a clean architecture solution: https://nurcahyaari.medium.com/how-i-implement-clean-code-architecture-on-golang-projects-68be58830621